# Can We use AMQP Protocol using http proxy?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, http-proxy

I require to interact to RabbitMQ using java client. As, enterprise environment are restrictive for I would require to raise firewall request. But, I came to know for port 443 and HTTPs or HTTP post we don't require firewall.

**Is it possible to publish request and get response for RabbitMQ using HTTP Proxy**

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can configure the amqp port

```
cp /usr/share/doc/rabbitmq-server-[rabbitmq version]/rabbitmq.config.example /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

Then search for

```
%%{tcp_listeners, [5672]}
```

And remove ‘%%’,
change 5672 to opened port, Then restart rabbitmq server.

or you will need to use socks as another solution